# How to filter cloudwatch logs using boto3 in python

Tags: python, aws-api-gateway, boto3, amazon-cloudwatch

I'd like to filter the logs from API Gateway with Cloudwatch.

Here is a sample of my logs:

```
(f810f3b1-5aqa-4af1-be31-bq10d3w99fqp) Endpoint request body after transformations: {"domain":"example.com"}
(f810f3b1-5aqa-4af1-be31-bq10d3w99fqp) HTTP Method: POST, Resource Path: /v/
(f810f3b1-5aqa-4af1-be31-bq10d3w99fqp) API Key: **************
(f810f3b1-5aqa-4af1-be31-bq10d3w99fqp) Method request path: {}
(f810f3b1-5aqa-4af1-be31-bq10d3w99fqp) Method request query string: {0.49120039624=}
```

My goal is to filter only the @message containing the request body to get the domain from it using boto3. Here's my code:

```
query = "fields @timestamp, @message | filter @message in ['domain']"

response_query = client.start_query(
        logGroupName=log_group, 
        startTime=int((datetime.now() - timedelta(hours=5)).timestamp()),
        endTime=int(datetime.now().timestamp()),
        queryString=query,
        limit=1000
    )
```

=> `{'results': [], 'statistics': {....}`
I'm getting no result from this query, do you have any idea why?

Comment: Could you try `like`? `filter @message like /domain/`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is to use `like` operator for fuzzy match. `in` operator in CloudWatch query is similar to it in other languages like Python,

```py
>>> 'a' in ['a', 'b']
True
```

`in` only checks for exact matches. Its typical usage in CloudWatch is to check low-cardinality set membership in the discovered log fields. For example, the discovered log field `@type` in Lambda logs indicates the type of a log message in a lambda invocation. The possible values are `START`, `END`, `REPORT`. In other words, the cardinality of this set is 3, which is pretty low. Then I can use the following query to get a glance of how the duration and max memory usage look like in the recent invocations.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @type in ['REPORT']
| sort @timestamp desc
```